# How can I return multiple node types in a single query with Neo4j GraphQL?

Tags: neo4j, graphql, cypher

I'm trying to return results from different node types in a single query:

```
        MATCH (this)-[a:WROTE]->(wrote:Post)
        WHERE a.date_added IS NOT NULL
        WITH COLLECT(wrote{ .*, date_added: a.date_added, typename: 'WROTE' }) as updates1, this
        MATCH (this)-[a:FOLLOWS]->(umb)
        WHERE (umb:User or umb:Movie or umb:Blog) AND a.date_added IS NOT NULL
        WITH updates1 + COLLECT(umb{ .*, date_added: a.date_added, typename: 'FOLLOWED' }) as allUpdates
        UNWIND allUpdates as update
        RETURN update
        ORDER BY update.date_added DESC
        LIMIT 5
```

And this works in the Neo4j browser, but it doesn't work in a GraphQL query. Where I'm using the Neo4j GraphQL library.

```
    updates: [PostMovieUser!]! @cypher(statement: """
        MATCH (this)-[a:WROTE]->(wrote:Post)
        ...
        (above query)
        ...
    """),
```

`union PostMovieUser = Post | Movie | User`

This is my error:

```
"message": "Invalid input ']': expected \"NOT\" or an expression (line 12, column 79 (offset: 632))\n\"LIMIT 5\", {this: this, auth: $auth, cypherParams: $cypherParams}, false) |    ] } as this\"\n                                                                               ^",
```

This is the GraphQL query:

```
query get_user_updates {
    users (where: { id: "YSCbEHFxm0gnXOPEKmRb8WUVOj2"}) {
    updates{
      __typename
    }
  }
}
```

---

Any idea?

Comment: Hi. Could you post the query that throws this error?

Comment: Hi @angrykoala it's the first query at the top

Comment: Sorry, I meant the GraphQL query

Comment: Ok @angrykoala I just added it! Curious what you think!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug with the `@cypher` directive. When executing your query, the full Cypher running in Neo4j is the following:

```
MATCH (this:User)
WHERE this.id = $this_id
RETURN this { updates: [this_updates IN apoc.cypher.runFirstColumn("MATCH (this)-[a:WROTE]->(wrote:Post)
WHERE a.date_added IS NOT NULL
WITH COLLECT(wrote{ .*, date_added: a.date_added, typename: 'WROTE' }) as updates1, this
MATCH (this)-[a:FOLLOWS]->(umb)
WHERE (umb:User or umb:Movie or umb:Blog) AND a.date_added IS NOT NULL
WITH updates1 + COLLECT(umb{ .*, date_added: a.date_added, typename: 'FOLLOWED' }) as allUpdates
UNWIND allUpdates as update
RETURN update
ORDER BY update.date_added DESC
LIMIT 5", {this: this, auth: $auth}, false) |    ] } as this
                                              ^
                                            Note this empty space
```

The invalid blank space between `|` and `]` is usually where the projection of your query is, however, in this case, you are not returning any data, only metadata.
As I mentioned, this seems to be a bug with the library `@neo4j/graphql`, but a simple workaround would be to return some data, for instance:

```
query get_user_updates {
    users (where: { id: "YSCbEHFxm0gnXOPEKmRb8WUVOj2"}) {
    updates{
      __typename
      ... on Post {
        name
      }
      ... on Movie {
        name
      }
      ... on User {
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above query (with whatever parameters you have in Post and Movie) seems to work fine.

Comment: Yep adding some data worked (to be honest I didn't know how to call the data for a mixed type node, so the `... on Post` syntax was helpful, thank you very much). I'm receiving `Invalid input for function 'labels()': Expected a Node, got: Map{name -> String(\"` - presumably this is due to the `umb{ .*, date_...` part but this format typically works when returning a single Node type. Does it not work for Union types?

Comment: And when removing the `umb{ .*` bit the error changes to: `Abstract type \"PostMovieUser\" must resolve to an Object type at runtime for field \"Update.update\". Either the \"PostMovieUser\" type should provide a \"resolveType\" function or each possible type should provide an \"isTypeOf\" function.`